# position independent code

Tags: assembly

Why

```
   push str1
```

when str1 is defined in .text int the same file,
is not good when we want to do position independent code?
When we push some label to the stack, is address is is address at static time? why?

Comment: This question is a little confusing and poorly worded, try to ask a clearer question.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever binaries are loaded, they get virtualized, this involves many things, but most importantly for PIC, it means the binary may be loaded and based at almost any address, so what PIC does to overcome this is make everything it possibly can use relative addressing (as these don't need to get fixed up for relocations).

In your example above, its impossible to create a relative address with just a `PUSH`, as the address that would be pushed would be an offset into the .text/.rodata section (or an absolution address made from some preferred base address), but it won't be adjusted to the binaries current virtual address, and as such you would need to adjust the address before pushing it (easiest would probably be via RIP relative addressing, so you'd do `PUSH [RIP + <dist from $here to string aka str1 - $>]`).